# About Generating Sitelinks Searchbox

Tags: google-sitelink-searchbox

I have used below given Schema.org code on my website, but still, I am not getting site links.

```html
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
 "@context": "https://schema.org/",
 "@type": "WebSite",
 "name": "website-name",
 "url": "https://website-name.com.au",
 "potentialAction": {
   "@type": "SearchAction",
   "target": "https://prabingautam.com.au/?s={search_term_string}",
   "query-input": "required name=search_term_string"
 }
}
</script>
```

Moreover, I am confused about which `query-input` to use to get the site link search box. Either

```json
"query-input": "required name=search_term_string"
```

or

```json
"query-input": "required name=searchbox_target"
```

Comment: Why `searchbox_target`? Where is this value coming from?

Comment: So you suggest adding "query-input": "required name=search_term_string" ?? I have seen searchbox_target in some of the sites that are generating search box in Google SERP.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the same value you used as placeholder in `target`.

```json
"target": "https://prabingautam.com.au/?s={search_term_string}",
"query-input": "required name=search_term_string"
```

```json
"target": "https://prabingautam.com.au/?s={searchbox_target}",
"query-input": "required name=searchbox_target"
```

```json
"target": "https://prabingautam.com.au/?s={foobar}",
"query-input": "required name=foobar"
```

You can choose whatever you like. There is no reason not to use `search_term_string` (this value gets used in [Google’s examples](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/sitelinks-searchbox?hl=en), so copy-pasting the code would be easier).